# Send a command into a running docker

Tags: oracle, bash, docker

I'm trying to start oracle lsnrctl in a running server.

Here is my command (run from host server):

```
until [ ! -z `docker exec -it my_docker bash -c "lsnrctl start" | grep successfully`]; do echo "init_demo: waiting for TNS listener to start";sleep 0.1;done
```

The output is an infinity loop of:

`init_demo: waiting for TNS listener to start`

When i try to run (from host server):

`docker exec -it tr-db bash -c 'lsnrctl start'`

I get:

`bash: lsnrctl: command not found`

However, after login to the docker server, i'm able to run the command, and get the expected result.

What wrong with by bash command?

---

Added later:
The problem was a path issue. However, i still have a problem with the whole command. The following command is working:

docker exec -it my_docker bash -c "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl start" | grep successfully

However, when i run the following command:
until [ ! -z `docker exec -it my_docker bash -c "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl start" | grep successfully`]; do echo "init_demo: waiting for TNS listener to start";sleep 0.1;done

I get:
bash: [: missing `]'

Comment: Wild guess: When you login interactively to the docker server, some environment variables are set (e.g. `ORACLE_HOME` / `PATH`) that are not set when using `docker exec`.

Comment: it may  help to see your Dockerfile, do you have various `ENV xxx yyy` for defining all the Oracle stuff?

Comment: I found the issue. However, i still have a problem with the whole command. I edited my original post. Can you please take a look?

Comment: can you have an alias in an environment variable, by putting in your Dockerfile something like `ENV myalias my_long_oracle_command` and building again your container? Then your command should be sort and your environment variable available.

Comment: @user2915097 Thanks! What about the other problem? (i edited my question above). Can you please look at this?

Comment: try `until [ ! -z docker exec -it my_docker bash -c "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl start | grep successfully" ]; do echo "init_demo: waiting for TNS listener to start";sleep 0.1;done` anyway, the closing " should be at the end of the command you give to `docker exec`